# node js Mngodb print objects from level of document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to print out the formatted results of documents in my mongo db,

I can print out the top level results of the document but I cant access the lower ones

```js
/** 
* Paste one or more documents here
*/
{
  "title": "Mr",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "mobile": "00000000",
  "email": "J.Doe@doe.com",
  "homeaddress": [
    {
      "line1": "Calle Baja",
      "line2": "Long Road",
      "town": "Fake town",
      "city": "Madrid",
      "postecode": "D6WN7NDW"
    }
  ],
  "Shippingaddress": [
    {
      "line1": "Long View",
      "line2": "Cave Street",
      "town": "FakeTown2",
      "city": "Waterford",
      "postecode": "D677W4WH1"
    }
  ],
  "Orders": [
    {
      "Model": "Apple iPhone 13",
      "purchase_date": {
        "$date": "2019-04-03T20:28:46.765Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above is what one of my documents looks like,

Please find below my current code which is printing out the top level doccuments _id down to email, howver I want to be able to print all the results from the selected doccument so including homeaddress, shippingaddress and Order.

```js
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

async function main() {

    const uri = "mongodb+srv://.......:.............mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.connect();



        await findCustomer(client, {
            findOneCustomer: 1
        });

    } finally {
        // Close the connection to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.close();
    }
}

main().catch(console.error);



async function findCustomer(client, {
    title = "Ms",
    findOneCustomer = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
} = {}) {

    const cursor = client.db("phoneStore").collection("csPhoneStore")
        .find({
                title:title
            }
        )
        .limit(findOneCustomer);

    // Store the results in an array
    const results = await cursor.toArray();

    // Print the results
    if (results.length > 0) {
        console.log(`Found Customer with title Ms:`);
        results.forEach((result, i) => {

            console.log();
            console.log(`_id: ${result._id}`);
            console.log(`title: ${result.title}`);
            console.log(`First name: ${result.firstName}`);
            console.log(`Last name: ${result.lastName}`);
            console.log(`mobile: ${result.mobile}`);
            console.log(`email: ${result.email}`);
            console.log(`homeaddress: ${result.homeaddress.line1}`);
            console.log(`..........`);
        });
    } else {
        console.log(`No Customer found`);
    }
}
```